# Need help creating a linq select

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I need some help creating an LINQ select, i have a table with some columns in it, but only 2 of interest to this problem.

```
userid, type
```

Now this table have many thousands entries, and I only want the top, let’s say 50. So far so good, but the hard part is that there a lot of rows in success that should only be counted as 1.
Example

```
Type  UserId
============
Add   1
Add   1
Add   1
Add   2
```

I would like this to only be counted as 2 in the limit of rows I am taking out, but I would like all the rows to be outputted still.
Is this possible with a single SQL request, or should I find another way to do this?

Edit: I can add columns to the table, with values if this would solve the problem. 
Edit2: Sotred procedures are also an solution

Example 2: This should be counted as 3 rows

```
Type  UserId
============
Add   1
Add   1
Add   2
Add   1
```

Comment: I think this is hard. Linq and SQL are good at set operations, not at sequential processing. Classic `foreach` is more suited here.

Comment: Yeah, but i would not like to fetch more then needed from the database, in theory could there more then 1000 rows in a sequence

Comment: I see a stored procedure looming...

Comment: a stored procedure would be fine, i just have no clue how to make it :D

Comment: OK, you might want to rephrase your question and add sql and stored procedure tags to attract the db crackajacks.

Comment: 'just' LINQ could do it (writing some operator) - but not with SQL/Entities as Gert mentioned - SP-s I guess too

Comment: I chose to rewrite my solution, so instead of doing the merging when the data is extracted will it now do it when it is inserted into the database, (I use JSON serilized arrays to keep the data). I will keep this open ontill an solution is found though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you stuck on LINQ?

Add a PK identity.
Order by PK.
Use a DataReader and just count the changes.
Then just stop when the changes count is at your max.

If you are not in a .NET environment then same thing with a cursor.

Since LINQ is deferred you might be able to just order in LINQ and then on a ForEach just exit.

Comment: I would like to stick with my repository, but this would propperly be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not close to a computer right now so I'm not sure is 100% correct syntax wise, but I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
data.Select(x => new {x.Type, x.UserId})
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
    .Take(50);
```

Comment: I have not realy worked with groupby in a long time, but as i remember will it not group all the entries into 1 single entry?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the other condition that it should only group the ones next to each other, I'll give it more thought on the solution and come back with an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it with Linq, but it may be a LOT slower than a traditional `for` loop. One way would be:

```
data.Where((s, i) => i == 0 || 
                     !(s.Type == data[i-1].Type && s.UserId == data[i-1].UserId))
```

That would skip any "duplicate" items that have the same Type and UserID as the "previous" item.

However this ONLY works if `data` has an indexer (an array or something that implements `IList`).  An `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` would not work.  Also, it is almost certainly not translatable to SQL so you'd have to pull ALL of the results and filter in-memory.

If you want to do it in SQL I would try either scanning a cursor and filling a temp table if one of the values change or using a common table expression that included a `ROW_NUMBER` column, then doing a look-back sub-query similar to the Linq method above:

```
WITH base AS
(
SELECT 
    Type,
    UserId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ??? ) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
)
SELECT b1.Type, b1.UserId
FROM base b1
LEFT JOIN base b2 ON b1.RowNum = b2.RowNum - 1
WHERE (b1.Type <> b2.Type OR b1.UserId <> b2.UserId)
ORDER BY b1.RowNum
```

Comment: This is what i want to avoid, as in theory the table could more many thousands of entries big!

Comment: Hmm i can not the the sql you made to work, but if i read it correctly dose it no only return the value that are diffrent?

Comment: It should return any row that is different that the next row. The last row should be included since the `b2` values will be NULL at that point. Are you getting an error or just the wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LINQ, but I think it might be easier to go the "for(each) loop" route...

```
data.Select((x, i) => new { x.Type, x.UserId, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Type = g.Key,
        Items = g
            .Select((x, j) => new { x.UserId, i = x.i - j })
    })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => new { g.Type, x.UserId, x.i }))
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Type, x.i })
    .Take(50);
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => new { x.Type, x.UserId }));
```